# how to add files cache policy to static files in nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

in nuxt 3 i have this code:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
        const url = event.node.req.url;
        const maxage = url.match(/(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|css|js|mjs|woff)/) ? 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 : 60 * 60;
        appendHeader(event, "Cache-Control", `max-age=${maxage} s-maxage=${maxage}`);
        }
    else {
        appendHeader(event, "Cache-Control",`max-age=${120} s-maxage=${120}`);
    }
})
```

it`s work but only image getting cache policy [css,js,woff] file in their header nothing is set

i try this in nuxt.config

```
routeRules: {
    "/img/**": { headers: { 'cache-control': `public,max-age=${year},s-maxage=${year}`} },
    "/_nuxt/**": { headers: { 'cache-control':`public,max-age=${year},s-maxage=${year}`} },
}
```

but it is`t working

Answer (score 1):

You can use nginx configuration to achieve this requirement

```
server {

    # for specific suffix
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|css|js|mjs|woff)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    }

    # for specific routes
    location ~ ^/(img|_nuxt)/ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    }
}
```

don't forget to reload the nginx after changing

```bash
sudo nginx -s reload
```